# How do you pass parameters to the constructor when creating an anonymous class in D

Tags: d

I get how to create an anonymous class

```
class A {}

class B {
    A anonymous = new class A { ... };
}
```

But if A has a constructor, and no default constructor.

```
class A {
    init(string someArg) {
    }
}

class B {
    A anonymous = new class A { ... };???
}
```

How do I pass the parameter to that constructor?

Comment: Does it need to be an anonymous class? Also consider using a delegate if it's appropriate.

Comment: yeah, i tried. But the class will need 3 "per instance defined" functions, and with delegates the parameter list became way to big and messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement a default constructor which calls the parent constructor with `super`:

```
class A
{
    this(string someArg) {}
}

void main()
{
    A anonyomus = new class A {
        this()
        {
            super("Hello");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Tried this, give me an error saying "'this' is only defined in non-static member functions, not *ParentClassName*",
And I also kinda assume this makes sense, Java for example does not allow for constructors in anonymous classes.

Comment: More specifically, i found that this does not work if to set a instance property of a class, e.g.:
class B {
    A anonymous = new A { ... }
}

Comment: `class B { A anonymous = new A { ... } }` probably does not do what you want. It will attempt to create A **during compilation**. If you want to instantiate A during B's instantiation, you need to do it in B's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to not use an anonymous class and instead just define a nested one.

```
class A {
    this(string someArg) {
    }
}

void main() {
    class not_really_anonymous : A {
        this(string a) { super(a); }
    }

    A anonymous = new not_really_anonymous("arg");
}
```

Since you can define classes inside functions in D, you should be able to achieve basically the same thing with this technique. Then you define constructors like usual and new it like usual, just refer to the base class/interface when returning it.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
class A {
    this(string someArg) {}
}

class B {
    A anonymous;
    this() {
        anonymous = new class A {
            this() {
                super("hello");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

or

```cpp
class A {
    this(string someArg) { }
}

class B {
    A anonymous;
    this() {
        anonymous = new class("hello") A {
            this(T...)(T args) { super(args); }
        };
    }
}
```